# Installing CloudHealth agent on EC2 instance - Latest CloudHealth agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

We have a large number of EC2 instances, both Windows and Linux, and we have CloudHealth v 10.0.0.180 installed. I understand there are newer versions such as 10.0.0.220 but I can't find a definitive list of the versions and which one is the latest. I have an AWS custom doc that pushes CloudHealth v10.0.0.180 (see below) but if I update that doc to push 10.0.0.220 it says it succeeds but the version does not change. Below are the URLs I am using in the doc for both v 10.0.0.180 and 10.0.0.220. The full document code is below as well.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/remote-collector/agent/windows/18/CloudHealthAgent.exe\
```

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/remote-collector/agent/windows/22/CloudHealthAgent.exe\
```

```
{
  "description": "Download and Install CloudHealth Agents",
  "schemaVersion": "2.2",
  "mainSteps": [
    {
      "inputs": {
        "runCommand": [
          "Write-Output \"Installing CloudHealth Agent\"",
          "$url = \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/remote-collector/agent/windows/22/CloudHealthAgent.exe\"",
          "$output = \"C:\\CloudHealthAgent.exe\"",
          "$start_time = Get-Date",
          "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output",
          "C:\\CloudHealthAgent.exe /S /v\"/l* install.log /qn CLOUDNAME=aws CHTAPIKEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"",
          "Write-Output \"Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)\""
        ]
      },
      "name": "CloudHealthAgentWindows",
      "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
      "precondition": {
        "StringEquals": [
          "platformType",
          "Windows"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "inputs": {
        "runCommand": [
          "echo “Installing CloudHealth Agent”",
          "sudo yum install wget -y",
          "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/remote-collector/agent/v22/install_cht_perfmon.sh",
          "sudo sh install_cht_perfmon.sh 20 8fdf2776-eda0-441b-bca8-0566ded6daf1 aws;"
        ]
      },
      "name": "CloudHealthAgentLinux",
      "action": "aws:runShellScript",
      "precondition": {
        "StringEquals": [
          "platformType",
          "Linux"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went through updating the agents myself.  I had to uninstall the old agent, reboot the instance, and then I was able to successfully install the new (22) version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those that need to uninstall. This info also found in the actual install script of install_cht_perfmon.sh

## find / -name uninstall_cht_perfmon.sh

/opt/cht_perfmon/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cht_perfmon-0.0.71/misc/uninstall_cht_perfmon.sh

## sh /opt/cht_perfmon/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cht_perfmon-0.0.71/misc/uninstall_cht_perfmon.sh

** Uninstalling CHT Performance Agent ...
** ensuring /root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin contains sbin folders
** PATH = /root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
cht_perfmon_collector: trying to stop process with pid 3056...
cht_perfmon_collector: process with pid 3056 successfully stopped.
Stopping chtcollectd (via systemctl):                      [  OK  ]
error: package agent is not installed
agent has been uninstalled!
** Removing cht_perfmon ...
userdel: user cht_agent is currently used by process 2203
** Removing chtcollectd ...
** Removing collectd if it was installed by cht_agent ...
** Finished uninstall.